# Finding covariance matrix of sum of product of Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, covariance, moment-generating-functions

I have two sequences of random variables. $X_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$, identically distributed, with covariance matrix $K_X$ and $Y_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$, identically distributed, with covariance matrix $K_Y$, where $Y_i$'s are i.i.d. and $K_Y$ is a scaled identity matrix. $X_i$'s are independent of $Y_i$'s. Now if $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{m}X_iY_i$, I want to find the covariance matrix of $Z$.

For scalars $a_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$, the covariance matrix of $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_iY_i$ can be found out to be $a^TK_Ya$ using MGF. MGF can't readily be applied to this case. So how does onr compute $K_Z$, the covariance matrix of $Z$? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $Z$ is a single random variable, its covariance matrix is just a number, $\text{Var}(Z)$.  If I am allowed to assume $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are mean zero, then
\begin{align} \text{Var}(Z) = E(Z^2) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m E(X_i Y_i X_j Y_j) 
\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m E(X_i X_j)E(Y_i Y_j) 
\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m (K_X)_{i,j} (K_Y)_{i,j}
\\ &= \text{trace}(K_X K_Y) .
\end{align}
If they aren't mean zero, then a similar, but more complicated, formula will work.

Comment: Note $Z$ isn't a Gaussian random variable.